# Sonarqube java.lang.IllegalStateException: The action 'create_bitbucketcloud' is defined multiple times

Tags: java, sonarqube

I updated sonarqube from 8.9.8-community to 9.6.0-comunity. i faced below error. How can i fix ?

```
2022.08.20 14:58:48 WARN  web[][o.s.a.s.w.WebService$Action] The response example is not set on action api/analysis_cache/get
2022.08.20 14:58:48 WARN  web[][o.s.a.s.w.WebService$Action] The response example is not set on action api/alm_integrations/check_pat
2022.08.20 14:58:48 WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6a6824be-org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The action 'create_bitbucketcloud' is defined multiple times in the web service 'api/alm_settings'
2022.08.20 14:58:48 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6a6824be-org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The action 'create_bitbucketcloud' is defined multiple times in the web service 'api/alm_settings'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The action 'create_bitbucketcloud' is defined multiple times in the web service 'api/alm_settings'
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.WebService$NewController.createAction(WebService.java:177)
    at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.server.pullrequest.ws.action.CreateAction.define(Crea
```